# IQueryable dynamic set property

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

Who to set property from join expression

```
public interface IHiddenEntity
{
  bool Hidden { get; set;}
}
public interface IEntity 
{
   long Id { get; set;}
   string Name { get; set;}
}

public class Entity: IEntity, IHiddenEntity 
{
   public long Id { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public bool Hidden { get; set;}
}

public class Hidden 
{
   public string TableName {g et; set; }
   public long RecordId { get; set; }
}

public class Person: Entity{ ... }
```

```
public IQueryable<T> All(bool loadHidden = false)
  where T : class, IEntity, IHiddenEntity 
{
    string tableName = "<T> name";
    return from x in Context.Set<T>()
           join h in Context.Set<Hidden>().Where(record => record.TableName == tableName) on x.Id equals h.RecordId into hr
            from h_r in hr.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where loadHidden ? true : h_r == null
            select x;
}
```

But I can’t understand how to **set** the value in the **Hidden** field.

1. Only IQueryable needs to be returned, because there are still
   conditions for the method to execute.
2. It is also impossible to
   convert to IEnumerable: this is not the final value (see above).

UDP: 
*Options to create a selection for each model are not considered - a lot of models with a huge number of fields!*

Comment: Why do you have this `Hidden` entity/table? The process that sets these entities could just as well set the `Hidden` properties in the appropriate entities directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, found an idea.
Create wrapped object with needed properties and cast to entity type after query executed.

```
internal EntityWrapper<T>
{
      public T Model { get; set; }
      public bool Hidden { get; set; }
}
```

```
public IQueryable<T> All(bool loadHidden = false)
  where T : class, IEntity, IHiddenEntity 
{
    string tableName = "<T> name";
    var query = from x in Context.Set<T>()
           join h in Context.Set<Hidden>().Where(record => record.TableName == tableName) on x.Id equals h.RecordId into hr
            from h_r in hr.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new EntityWrapper<T>(){ Model = x, Hidden = h_r != null};

    if(!loadHidden)
        query = query.Where(x => !x.Hidden);
}
```

And cast after build sql query and results with wrapped object.

```
    Expression<System.Func<EntityWrapper<T>,T> castFunc = x => x.Select(wr => {wr.Model.Hidden = wr.Hidden; return wr.Model;});
```

Cast only `IEnumerable<EntityWrapper<T>>` object.

```
var result = castFunc(<query>.ToList());
```